# Elasticsearch query match multiple values to single field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

Trying to get documents matching values `X1` or `Y1` for field `ABC`. Tried both `must` or `should` queries, but not getting expected result. Can someone suggest what kind of query should I try? Using `HighLevelRestClient`.

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "ABC" : {
            "value" : "X1",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term" : {
          "ABC" : {
            "value" : "Y1",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

OR

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "ABC" : {
            "value" : "X1",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term" : {
          "ABC" : {
            "value" : "Y1",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ABC": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 2
          }
        }
      },
```

`mustNot` condition works fine. If I just reverse the condition and ignore fields values then I get the result.

X1 and Y1 are exact field values (Think enums)

```
BoolQueryBuilder x = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (SomeEnum enum : enums) { 
   x.should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("ABC",enum.name());
}
```

Still query returns all documents. This should have filtered the documents to matching values

Sample Doc

```
{
  "_index": "some_index",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "uyeuyeuryweoyqweo",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "A": true
    "ABC": "X1"
    "WS": "E"
  }
}, 
{
  "_index" : "some_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "uyeuyeuryweoyqweo1",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "A" : true,
    "ABC" : "Y1",
    "WS" : "MMM"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your mapping, sample docs and expected output?

Comment: Added more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not provided your mapping, possible cause is due to the mismatch of search time tokens to index-tokens.

As you are using `term` query which are not analyzed as mentioned in [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

> Returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.

It means that you documents in index must conatins the exact tokens as `X1` and `Y1` and if these fields are `text` fields and you have not defined any anlyzer than elasticsearch uses `standard` analyzer which `lowercases` the tokens, hence in index `x1` and `y1` would be stored and nothing will match.

**EDIT** : As suspected, issue was due to `term` query used on `text` fields, below query would give the expected results

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "ABC.keyword" : {
            "value" : "X1",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term" : {
          "ABC.keyword" : {
            "value" : "Y1",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added mapping

Comment: @java_dude got it, you just need to use the `should` and `ABC.keyword` in your query to get the expected output :)

Comment: Result returns all documents when using should. Added rest client code

Comment: @java_dude, could you show your sample and expected docs? you need both X1 and Y1 present or any one would suffice?

Comment: Document can have either. Need to pick all the documents matching values in the fiel. Added sample document

Comment: Added two sample document. Query should pick both of these.

Comment: @java_dude should query should bring both of your sample docs, can you try the query I provided in answer using postman or curl request against your index?

Comment: The query works using curl. Will try implementing it using HighLevelRestClient. Will update this post in 8 hours. Much appreciated your help.

Comment: Curl works but HighLevelRest Client does not. I will post a new question and refer it here

Comment: @java_dude thanks for marking answer  , were u able to solve using JHLRC?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
{"query":
{"bool":
{"filter":["must" : [{ "match" : { "ABC" : "X1 OR Y1"}}]}}
```